# H2 in memory database is getting confused between column name, and the value I want to use

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

Context : Trying to test a spring boot application, trying to initialize data via the data.sql file in the src/test/resources/ directory

I have the following in memory db :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;
```

I also have the following SQL table :

```
CREATE TABLE `roles` (
                       `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                       `name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
                       PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
                       UNIQUE KEY `UK_nb4h0p6txrmfc0xbrd1kglp9t` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and here is my insert statement (in data.sql)

```
INSERT INTO roles(name) VALUES ("ROLE_USER");
```

When I run my spring unit tests, I get this error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of URL [file:/Users/me/IdeaProjects/proj/out/test/resources/data.sql]: INSERT INTO roles(name) VALUES ("ROLE_USER"); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "ROLE_USER" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO roles(name) VALUES ("ROLE_USER") [42122-198]
```

To me, everything looks correct... I'm using a simple insert statement, on a table which definitely exists... and I am inserting a value which corresponds well with the column definition. But for some reason, it throws that error saying Column "ROLE_USER" does not exist, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! I found the solution - turns out that the SQL statement needed single quotes for the values... so the correct way would be :

```
INSERT INTO roles(name) VALUES ('ROLE_USER');
```

instead of :

```
INSERT INTO roles(name) VALUES ("ROLE_USER");
```